# AngularJS child directives linking function firing multiple times for each parent directive on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to wrap my head around angularjs directives. I have a parent directive, with 4 instances of it on my page. One of the parent directives contains an instance of the CHILD directive.

The child directive's linking function appears to run 4 times however, as I see the following in my console 4 times:

```
child linking function
```

Any idea why / how to fix? Thanks!

PARENT:

```
Module.directive 'collapseWidget', () ->
  directive =
    restrict:   'A'
    transclude: true
    template:   viewCollapseWidget
    scope: 
      title:        '@title'
      widgetThemis: '@widgetThemis'
      color:        '@color'
      model:        '='

    #replace: true
    compile: (element, attrs, transclusionFunc) ->
      (scope, iterStartElement, attrs) ->

        #if scope.buttons
          #console.log scope.buttons
        scope.collapsed = false

        scope.toggle = () ->
          scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed

        origElem   = transclusionFunc scope
        content    = origElem.text()
        scope.orig = content
        scope.obj  = content
```

CHILD:

```
Module.directive "myTable", ->
      directive =
        restrict: 'A'
        scope: 'isolate'
        link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
          console.log 'child linking function'
          return
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any console errors?

The reason I ask is that in your child 'myTable' directive you have scope defined as a String rather than an empty Object. It could be that scope is not isolated because of this and is using the parent scope instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm weighing in late, but the answer to this question is simple. The `link` function is going to get called as many times as you have instances of the directive.